# WordPress: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on line 130

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add my this code into head using wp_head action,

But I am getting this error `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on line 130`
line number 130 is on  `if ( !empty ( display_header_text() ) ) : ?>`

**Here is my code**

```
<?php
129:function _display_header_text() {
130:if ( !empty ( display_header_text() ) ) : ?>
131:<style type="text/css" id="_display_header_text">
132:    .mainHeader a img {
133:        display:none;
134:    }
135:</style>
136:<?php endif; }
137:add_action('wp_head','_display_header_text');
138:?>
139:
140:<?php
141:function _is_admin_bar_showing() {
142: if( is_admin_bar_showing() ):?>
143:<style type="text/css" id="_is_admin_bar_showing">
144:    .fixedHeader {
145:        top:32px;
146:    }
147:</style>
148:<?php endif; }
149:add_action('wp_head','_is_admin_bar_showing');
150:?>
```

my this code is working fine in localhost without any error, but this is sending error on live server.

any idea what is this? and how can I solve it?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you pointed out WHERE line 130 is, because your snippet very obviously does not have 130 lines. But you're probably doing something like `if (foo() = 37)`, trying to assign a value to a function, instead comparing: `if (foo() == 37)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's likely this line causing the error:

```
if ( !empty ( display_header_text() ) ) : ?>
```

As the [documentation for `empty()`](http://php.net/empty) states:

> Note:
>   Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty()` only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`. Instead, use `trim($name) == false`.

Comment: Note that it says it will result in a *parse* error, whereas OP is getting a *fatal* error.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I think the documentation is just wrong. See here: http://3v4l.org/XrWMf

Comment: Fair enough - wouldn't be the first time the docs were wrong XD

Comment: I cant upgrade my php version, because my hosting provider wont.
even on my request, that cause other peoples problem, its my hosting provider words,my current version is 5.1.70,

So tell me another solution , what should I do?

Comment: @Mr.beginner: Store the return value of `display_header_text()` in a variable before checking it with `empty()`. That is `$headerText = display_header_text(); if (!empty($headerText)) : ?>`.

Comment: Ah the perils of developing on XAMPP =) - I just did this inside of a class myself. 5.5 is so damn convenient I often code lazy and then get a WSOD on commit to staging in a 5.3 host.

Comment: @Amal Murali
Thank you so much it solve my problem also